# What is the conditional expression to put sell in the color of the bar in finescript?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I learned a conditional expression to change the color of the bar.
So I wondered.
Is there a conditional expression to place a sell order when the bar changes color?

if have a bar color #aaaaaa, #bbbbbb, #cccccc
I want to place a sell order at the first moment when it changes from another color to a #cccccc color

I've seen a lot of manuals, but I haven't seen anything that puts orders based on color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this multiple ways.

Let's say you have a variable `my_color` that holds the color information.

You can check if it is a new #cccccc, as below:

```
is_new_c = (my_color[1] != #cccccc) and (my_color == #cccccc)
```

Then use `is_new_c` as your sell condition.

Comment: If I already have sell conditions and want to add them to them, how can I set strategy.exit?
I know it bothers you, but I would really appreciate it if you could answer!

Comment: You cannot use this with `strategy.exit()`. You should use `strategy.close()`.

Comment: omg Sorry I'm curious, is there no way to use it as an exit? Why can't it only be used in close?

Comment: Also, is there a way to give you a count or give a good rating? I've been using the community for a while and I don't know how.

Comment: You cannot use `strategy.exit()` because this exit condition is not based on a price level (e.g. TP or SL). Here, you are looking for a condition, therefore you need to use `strategy.close()`.

Comment: First of all I would like to thank you!!
And can exit be used when changing the color of candles to SL?

Comment: Not really. Ideally, you should wait until the bar is closed to confirm the color change. `strategy.close` is ideal for cases like this. Why don't you want to use `strategy.close`?

Comment: Thank you very much If you were Korean, I would have given you a chicken with a gift icon lol